# How does the return keyword really work?

Tags: java

A simple code snippet calculating the factorial of a number below:

```
public class Main{

static int factorial(int number){       

    System.out.println("At factorial("+number+")");

    if (number == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    return number * factorial(number-1);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("factorial(4) = "+ factorial(4));


}
}
```

Here, I thought that when the value of the number becomes 1(due to recursion), it returns 1 every time and breaks out of the method and prints 1. But, it does return proper factorial value?
As per this: [Java - Does returning a value break a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661081/java-does-returning-a-value-break-a-loop), shouldn't it have returned 1 every time? How these 2 code snippet differ in returning a value?

Thank You

Comment: It returns to when the method was called. Draw out the method on paper

Comment: You should learn about the call stack.

Comment: **Run** the program. If you want to see the value you're returning add a log statement for that too. `int result = number * factorial(number-1); System.out.println("At factorial("+number+") = " + result); return result;` **Also**, `int` will *overflow* factorial quickly.

Comment: @Narasimhan i have tried to explain, please go thru

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to explain the whole process; refer to [this source](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/recursion/explanation-of-recursion/).

Prior to this you should have basic understanding of call stacks, recursion, and stack frames.

A *call stack* is a data structure used by the program to store information about the active subroutines. The main reason for having a call stack is so that the program can keep track of where a subroutine should return control to once it finishes executing.

A *stack frame* is a part of the call stack, and a new stack frame is created every time a subroutine is called. So, in our recursive `factorial()` method above, a new stack frame is created every time the method is called. The stack frame is used to store all of the variables for one invocation of a routine. So, remember that a call stack is basically a stack of stack frames.

---

Let's divide the process into 4 parts, since the number chosen is 4.

#### 1st Iteration

```
static int factorial(4){ 

    if (4 == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    return 4 * factorial(3);
}
```

#### 2nd Iteration

```
static int factorial(3){ 

    if (3 == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    return 3 * factorial(2);
}
```

#### 3rd Iteration

```
static int factorial(2){ 

    if (2 == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    return 2 * factorial(1);
}
```

#### 4th Iteration

```
static int factorial(1){ 

    if (1 == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    return 2 * factorial(number-1);
}
```

1. You can see that the first stack frame is created with a number equal to 4.
2. Then a call to `factorial(3)` is made – so the first call to `factorial(4)` does not run to completion because another call (`factorial(3)`) is made before the very first call to `factorial` can run to completion.
3. Same is the case for others.
4. A *stack frame* is used to hold the state of the first call to `factorial()`. It stores the local function variables (and their values) of the current invocation of `factorial()`, and it will also store the return address of the method that called it (since we are talking about the very first non-recursive invocation of `factorial()`, *whatever routine invoked `factorial()` in the first place is where Factorial would return when it is completely done with everything*).

Because the stack frame also stores the return address, the `factorial()` function knows where to return to when it finishes running

#### Process Execution

Finally, in the **4th** stack frame, we run into our base case, which
means the recursive calls are finished and then control is returned to
the **3rd** stack frame, where `factorial(1) * 2` is calculated to be
`2`, and then control is returned to the **2nd** stack frame where `factorial(2) * 3` is calculated to be `6`, and then control is
returned to the **1st** stack frame where `factorial(3) * 4` is
calculated to be `24`. Finally, our result of `24` is returned.

Comment: Keep in mind code ticks are for code and aren't meant to show emphasis ;) Quotes are to quote other media or to use parts of other articles and whatnot, and shouldn't be used to show emphasis either. I removed all of that stuff for you :) Good answer though.